# Multithreading Synchronisation

Tags: c++, multithreading, graphics, c++builder

I'm trying to write a multithreaded graphics manipulation program using Borland's C++ Builder 6 on WinXP SP3, but have run into (I think) a synchronisation issue, and can't figure out why.

Main Form (Form1) has a TPicture loaded from file. A copy of this is acquired by the thread via a Synchronize() call, and works fine. The thread does some work on the image, and in theory, it periodically updates the main Form image. The main Form also controls a machine, and is a 'First Resort' emergency stop, so blocking isn't an option. Everything is fine until the main Form gets hold of the working copy, or a copy of the working copy (sorry, but it's got to that) at which point the program hangs, and is only responsive to a 'program reset' from the IDE. A poor solution is to copy the working image to the Clipboard, and then, from the main Form, copy from the Clipboard to the main Form's image.

```
        //Synchronization routines:
//----------------------------------------------------------------
`void __fastcall ImageRout::update()
{
Form1->Image9->Picture->Bitmap->Assign(Imgcopy);
//never returns
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall ImageRout::getimage()
{
    Imgcopy->Assign(Form1->Image9->Picture);
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------

//do the initialisation things... Then,
//(data is a struct, loaded with image data via a Synchronize() call)
Imgcopy=new Graphics::TBitmap;
Imgcopy->Width=data.width;
Imgcopy->Height=data.height;    //size the bitmap
while(Imgcopy->Canvas->LockCount!=1)
{
    Imgcopy->Canvas->TryLock();
}  //have to Lock() the image or it gets lost... Somewhere
Synchronize(getimage);  //works fine

//do some work on Imgcopy

//"By the book"- attempt 1
//(rate (=15) is a 'brake' to stop every alteration being displayed)
update_count++;
if(update_count>rate)   //after a few iterations, update
{           //user interface
     Synchronize(update);  //fails: never returns from Synchronize call
     update_count=0;
}
```

After a lot of failed attempts, I came up with this.

```
//in the thread...

update_count++;
if(update_count>rate)
{
     EnterCriticalSection(&Form1->mylock1);
     Form1->tempimage->Assign(Imgcopy);        //tempimage is another bitmap, 
     InterlockedExchange(&Form1->imageready,1);//declared in the main Form
     LeaveCriticalSection(&Form1->mylock1);    //and is only ever accessed
     update_count=0;                           //inside a critical section
}

//...and in the main Form....

if(imageready==1)
{
     EnterCriticalSection(&mylock1);
     Image9->Picture->Bitmap->Assign(tempimage);     //Fails here
     InterlockedExchange(&gotimage,1);
     InterlockedExchange(&imageready,0);
     LeaveCriticalSection(&mylock1);
}
```

So, in desperation.

```
//in the thread...
update_count++;
if(update_count>rate)
{
     Synchronize(update);
     EnterCriticalSection(&Form1->mylock1);
     Form1->tempimage->Assign(Imgcopy);
     Clipboard()->Assign(Imgcopy);
     InterlockedExchange(&Form1->imageready,1);
     LeaveCriticalSection(&Form1->mylock1);  */
     update_count=0;
}

//and in the main Form...
if(imageready==1)
{
     EnterCriticalSection(&mylock1);
     if (Clipboard()->HasFormat(CF_BITMAP))
     {
          Image9->Picture->Bitmap->Assign(Clipboard());
     }
     InterlockedExchange(&gotimage,1);
     InterlockedExchange(&imageready,0);
     LeaveCriticalSection(&mylock1);
}
```

This last attempt works, albeit relatively slowly, because of the Clipboard overhead, and it's a poor crutch, at best. I suspect the Clipboard is enforcing an otherwise failed synchronisation effort, but, as I said earlier, I can't fathom why. What can be the issue?

Comment: It is not safe to access a VCL UI control from outside the context of the main UI thread. A worker thread must sync with the main thread to access them correctly. A critical section will not do that. However, a `TBitmap` object by itself is safe to use across thread boundaries *as long as* each thread locks the bitmap's `Canvas`. Just don't manipulate the `TImage`'s bitmap directly in a worker thread. Using an in-memory `TBItmap` is fine, and then synchronize with the main UI thread when you need to display the new `TBitmap` content. If you encounter a freeze, you are doing something wrong...

Comment: You don't need to use `Canvas->TryLock()`, just use `Canvas->Lock()` instead.  And don't forget to call `Canvas->Unlock()` when you are done.  Do not hold on to the lock for long periods of time.  Have the worker thread wait until a change a needed, then get the lock, make the change, unlock, and sync.  When the main UI thread detects a change, have it get the lock, read the new bitmap, and unlock.

Comment: I've found that if I don't lock the thread local images on creation, and leave them locked until deletion, the thread finishes up accessing NULL image pointers, or blank images. Does a Synchronize() call  only "postmessage" and return, or  does it wait for some response from the main Form before it returns? If it's the former, that would probably explain the Synchronize() call failure- we'd be working on the  image copy again, whist the main Form is trying to access it (code block 1, above), but even if that's the case, the critical section version's problem (code blocks 2 & 3) still exists.

Comment: DO NOT leave the bitmap canvas locked for the duration of the thread lifetime. Lock and unlock it on an as-needed basis instead. As for `TThread.Synchronize()`, it is synchronous. It posts a request to the main thread and does not exit until the request has been processed.  `TThread.Queue()`, on the other hand, is asynchronous. It does not wait for the request to be processed.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your comments, Remy. They shook me out of a "tizzy" I'd got myself into whilst trying to solve the problem. I'd forgotten that Windows needs to move memory blocks around, and can't do this if locked them.

The initial problem of the Synchronize(update) call (code block 1 above) was caused by my still having the working copy (Imgcopy) locked (from inside the thread) during the call, preventing the main Form from subsequently accessing it. I suspect (but haven't investigated- *that* code has gone) the same root cause was at work in code block 2.

Locking every bitmap just prior to access, and unlocking immediately afterwards has solved this problem.

Peter O, thanks for your edit- I didn't realise there was so much overhead in my initial post.